# Drop ou Truncate tabela com 80 milhões de registros?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela com 80 milhões de registros, limpa-la sem excluir a tabela, pois a mesma é usada em tempo real, qual a melhor sugestão para que eu possa limpar essa tabela sem perder a funcionalidade da mesma? E qual forma é a mais rápida e indicada?

Comment: A tabela possui chaves estrangeiras? Um DELETE FROM 'TABELA' não é o que você está precisando?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Truncate – é um comando DDL que remove todas as linhas de uma tabela.
>   Não pode ser revertido, é mais rápido e não usa tanto o espaço como
>   desfazer um delete.
>
> Delete – é um comando DML usado para remover linhas de uma tabela.
>   Depois de executado podem ser executados os comandos COMMIT e ROLLBACK
>   para confirmar ou desfazer a operação. Quando não é especificada uma
>   condição (WHERE) todas as linhas são deletadas.
>
> Drop – é um comando DDL  que remove tabelas do banco de dados, todas
>   as linhas, privilégios e indices serão apagados. Não pode ser
>   revertida.

O mais recomendável seria um truncate, porém talvez apenas um delete iria resolver.

Comment: No caso dele, caso não haja chaves estrangeiras, apenas o simples DELETE FROM 'TABELA' já o atende.

Comment: Utilizei o truncate mesmo, pois eu precisava apenas limpar os registros da tabela, sem mexer na estrutura da mesma, funcionou e foi instantâneo.

Comment: A respeito de "tanto o Drop quanto o Truncate apaga a tabela", TRUNCATE não apaga a tabela mas sim o conteúdo da tabela.

Comment: Sim realmente, já corrigi o post